# Hacer que dplyr::lag() tome el último valor que no sea NA

Tags: r

Quiero sumar cada valor con su anterior y que cuando el anterior sea NA tome el último valor que no es NA

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(a = c(2, 4, 15, NA, 6))
df %>% mutate(b = a - lag(a))

     a     b
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     2    NA
2     4     2
3    15    11
4    NA    NA
5     6    NA
```

Sin embargo el resultado que deseo obtener es:

```
      a     b
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     2    NA
2     4     2
3    15    11
4    NA     0
5     6    -9
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2):

Me respondo a mí mismo:

```
a %>% mutate(b = zoo::na.locf0(a), 
             b = b - lag(b),
             b = if_else(is.na(b), a, b))

 a     b
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     2     2
2     4     2
3    15    11
4    NA     0
5     6    -9
```

Aunque quizá exista una solución mejor o más elegante. No sé.

Answer (score 2):

Lo que planteaste en tu respuesta es sin duda una forma muy adecuada de resolverlo. Eventualmente si no quisieras la dependencia con `zoo`, tampoco es complejo resolverlo con una función ad-hoc súper simple:

```
last_non_na <- function(x) {
  non_na <- NA
  for(i in seq(x)) {
    if (is.na(x[i])) {
      x[i] <- non_na
    } else { non_na <- x[i] }
  }
  x
}

df %>% 
  mutate(b = last_non_na(a),
         b = b - lag(b, default=0))
```

Comment: Gracias Patricio, me guardo la función.